# How do i create a custom ng build --qa Angular 5.2

Tags: angular

I would like to create ng build --qa where it picks up environment.qa.ts and does AOT, bundling and Dead code elimination but not Minification and Uglification

How would I do this in Angular 5.2

Answer (score 5):

In angular6 we are doing it like below:

1. Create your own environment.qa.ts file inside environments folder. Where you can edit the
   details or you can add some more details like URL for your qa environment:

   ```
   export const environment = {
     production: false,
     URL:'http://something:8200'
   }
   ```
2. Now in angular.json you will have to add the **qa** configuration inside **configurations** and also you need to mention file replacement over there.

   "configurations": {

   ```
           "qa": {
             "fileReplacements": [
               {
                 "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                 "with": "src/environments/environment.qa.ts"
               }
             ],
             "optimization": true,
             "outputHashing": "all",
             "sourceMap": false,
             "extractCss": true,
             "namedChunks": false,
             "aot": true,
             "extractLicenses": true,
             "vendorChunk": false,
             "buildOptimizer": true
           }
         }
   ```

   It's up to you, if you want buildOptimizer, optimizationand all to be done in qa build you can use these value to be true or you can remove these options.

   3.Finally run your build with this command **ng build --configuration=qa**

Comment: I am using angular 5.2 how would I do it in angular 5.2

Comment: @kumar if you follow above are you getting any error?

Comment: This could also help you [link](https://medium.com/@amcdnl/custom-environments-for-angular-cli-4ce0b82da83b)

Comment: Is it possible to run it as `ng build --qa`? If we can run `ng build --prod`, this should also be possible somehow.

Comment: @DirtyMind what happen if set `production: true` to qa environment?

Answer (score 1):

For angular 5 version you just need to have the environment files created, e.g:

```
/src/environments/environment.prod.ts
                  environment.qa.ts
                  environment.ts
```

Then in angular.cli.json:

```
{
 ...
 app [
 {
  ...
  "environments": {
    "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
    "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts",
    "qa": "environments/environment.qa.ts"
  }
```

And from the console you just have to execute the following command:

```
ng build --env=qa
```

You can do a test and see that the values taken in that case are the ones from the environment.qa.ts

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing angular6, you need to add your `environment.qa.ts` to your `angular.json` configurations.

After doing so in both the `build` and `configuration` section, simply run `ng build --configuration=qa`

Answer (score 0):

Create your **environment.qa.ts** inside **environments** folder.
 [image]

Then go to angular.json file and
 Under configurations options add the configuration for QA as

```
"qa": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.qa.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
```

[image: So the overall code will look like]

And then go to **package.json** and add the script section as below

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod --aot --build-optimizer",
    "build:prod": "node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --c prod --build-optimizer --aot",
    "build:qa": "node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --c qa --build-optimizer --aot",
    "build:dev": "node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --c dev --build-optimizer --aot",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
```

then you can run `npm run build:qa` for qa, and `npm run build:dev` for dev and `npm run build:prod` for prod

Answer (score 0):

My solution is simple:
I create another file in environments folder [image]

Then go to angular.json file and Under configurations options add the configuration for QA as[image]

And from the console I execute the following command: `ng build --configuration qa`